# ILMerge issue error code 1

Tags: ilmerge

I was made aware that ilmerge is a console application but when I run it, it runs for one second then closes. So below is the pre-build code I'm trying to use and it's giving this issue.

```
Error   1   The command "ilmerge /out:F:\Users\Tom\Desktop\New folder\project\bin\Release\SkypePWN4G-1.5.5.0.exe F:\Users\Tom\Desktop\New folder\project\bin\Release\SkypePWN4G-1.5.5.0.exe F:\Users\Tom\Desktop\New folder\project\bin\Release\JSNet.dll F:\Users\Tom\Desktop\New folder\project\bin\Release\NAudio.dll" exited with code 1.   Pwnage
```

Pre-build code:

```
ilmerge /out:$(TargetDir)SkypePWN4G-1.5.5.0.exe $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)JSNet.dll $(TargetDir)NAudio.dll
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Run ILMerge with the /log flag for more information
2. If you are running this as part of your build process, I believe your build actions should be *post* build actions, not pre-build actions
3. Try another tool like [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura). Costura has the added benefit of being able to merge dlls into WPF applications.

Comment: Wow, that tool is amazing, I installed the plugin and it works wonders. Thank you so much, I've been stressing about my new version release that now requires dll's. And this just saved my ass cause my updater in the old versions does not support downloading multiple files like the dll's.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a folder named "merged" in your target location? I had the same problem and solved it by creating a new "merged" folder in somePath/bin/Debug.